# Prove Through Induction That $\mathbb{R}^N$ has only trivial finite subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can I show using induction on $n$ that $\mathbb{R}^N$ has only trivial subgroups? I was advised to use the isomorphism between  $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^{N+1}/\mathbb{R}^N$... But the correspondence principle only discusses subsets containing the kernel. How do I show there are no others?

Comment: A finite subgroup of $\mathbb{R}^n$ must have every element annihilated by some integer--how many elements of $\mathbb{R}^n$ do you know that satisfy this?

Comment: Why induction??

Comment: I don't know, that's what the question was discussing.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Induction is implicitly used in stating that $\mathbb{R}^n$ is torsion-free: the direct sum of two torsion-free groups is torsion-free.

Comment: You don't need induction to see this - an arbitrary product of torsion-free groups is torsion-free.

Answer (score 2):

Finite groups are torsion. Hence, a torsion-free group has no non-trivial finite subgroups.

Comment: Can you do it with induction? I don't know what torsion is, and that wasn't the point of the question.

Comment: Torsion = every element has finite order. It is trivial that $(\mathbb{R}^n,+)$ is torsion-free.